# как распарсить CSV по знаку, который нужно игнорировать в некоторых случаях?

Tags: java, csv

Есть CSV вида

```
1;2;3;4;"abc.com/d=e;q;w;e"
```

чтобы разбить строку, в качестве символа беру ";", но т.к. в url этот знак присутствует, то получаю неверный результат. csv достаточно большой и обрабатывать по символам строку-дорого. есть какой-нить способ? сейчас я считываю построчно и делаю stroka.split(";"), как составить регулярное выражение, которое бы учитывало кавычки?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что использование регулярки *дешевле*, чем ручной посимвольный разбор?

Comment: во всяком случае время сэкономлю ручной реализации

Comment: Я погуглил за вас: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double/366532#366532

Answer (score 1):

Формат `CSV` не так прост как кажется на первый взгляд.

Проще всего взять готовую библиотеку для парсинга. Например [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: да, я так и сделал, но все равно спасибо.